# Visual Studios Online Packages fails with 401 unauthorized - even though I have permission

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget-package-restore, azure-devops

I seem to be getting a strange 401 unauthorized error when attempting to connect to my organization's VSO package store, but only in Visual Studios 2015 from my home network.

From chrome I'm able to access the repository and see the json, and I have full access to the TFS portion (backlogs, code repositories, builds, releases, and packages), but when I connect to the nuget repository from visual studios 2015, I get 401 unauthorized.

When I first start VS, if I choose manage nuget packages, it will prompt for credentials, and after I enter my credentials, it then shows nothing, but the package restore fails.

So then I tried using the personal access token (from the packages screen in visual studios online - option 2) which had me use nuget from command line to add the repository with a specific username and password, then rather than get "401 Unauthorized" I get "Failed to read metadata" and the project name in the path is now a guid rather than the actual project name, but if I check in Tools->Nuget Package Manager-> Package Manager Settings -> Package Sources, it shows the correct path.

I even tried removing the source it created then reloading visual studios and connecting via Manage Nuget Packages and using the supplied username/password to connect via the credentials popup mentioned earlier.

Has anyone dealt with this?  It's working fine when on-location, but if I'm working from a distance, it is failing.

My visual studios is logged in with my organization account, however Windows is not, I'm not sure if that makes a different or not, since I was able to clone all the repositories I needed, just not able to access the package source.

Thank you for any help in tracking this down.

Comment: Do you have all the latest VS/Nuget updates?

Comment: So it works in your company but does not work at home on the same machine and VS version? And which version of VS and Nuget are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have assigned this answer to chief7 from the comments on the original question, but unfortunately I can't mark a comment as an answer.

In the end, the issue was that I had Nuget Package Manager version 3.1.0 installed, but the Visual Studio Online packages need Nuget version **3.3.0**.

The update didn't appear in my "notifications" section of visual studio (flag in the top right), but did appear when I went to Tools->Extensions and Updates.

After installing the update, everything began working correctly.